# Handling linear upsampling audio array

Tags: c++, arrays, audio

I have a real-time signal coming in sample by sample, I need to do 4x upsampling on it. I have this class from musicdsp.org:

```
#ifndef TD_INTERPOLATOR_H_INCLUDED
#define TD_INTERPOLATOR_H_INCLUDED

/************************************************************************
*    Linear interpolator class                                            *
************************************************************************/

class interpolator_linear
{
public:
    interpolator_linear() {
        reset_hist();
    }

    // reset history
    void reset_hist() {
        d1 = 0.f;
    }


    // 4x interpolator
    // out: pointer to float[4]
    inline void process4x(float const in, float *out) {
        float y = in-d1;
        out[0] = d1 + 0.25f*y;    // interpolate
        out[1] = d1 + 0.5f*y;
        out[2] = d1 + 0.75f*y;
        out[3] = in;
        d1 = in; // store delay
    }


    }

private:
    float d1; // previous input
};

#endif // TD_INTERPOLATOR_H_INCLUDED
```

I assume the above is correct. Now the question is how do I return the array elements individually?

```
void TD_OSclip::subProcessClip4( int bufferOffset, int sampleFrames )
{

    float* in  = bufferOffset + pinInput.getBuffer();
    float* outputt = bufferOffset + pinOutput.getBuffer();



    for( int s = sampleFrames; s > 0; --s )
    {


        float input = *in;


//upsample 4x Linear --How should I call it here?

interpolator_linear::process4(input, what should be here??);

////I need all the seperate out arrays elements for the next stage

//do process
float clip = 0.5f;
float neg_clip = -0.5f;

float out0 = std::max( neg_clip, std::min( clip, out[0] ) );
float out1 = std::max( neg_clip, std::min( clip, out[1] ) );
float out2 = std::max( neg_clip, std::min( clip, out[2] ) );
float out3 = std::max( neg_clip, std::min( clip, out[3] ) );


//lowpass filter ommitted for briefness

float out0f = out0;
float out1f = out0;
float out2f = out0;
float out3f = out0;



//downsample

float output1 = ( out0f + out1f + out2f + out3f ) / 4.f;


                *outputt = output1;

            ++in;
                ++outputt;


    }

    }
```

P.S. I am well aware that linear interpolation is bad, but it's the simplest I've seen. And I'm new to coding so 'ease of implementation' trumps performance at this stage.

Regards
Andrew

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "return the array elements individually".

Comment: I need out[0], out[1], out[2], out[3], the class just returns a pointer I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a buffer to process4 which can hold 4 floating point values.
Secondly, you need to instantiate interpolater_linear in order to use it.

```
interpolator_linear interp; // you'll want to make this a member of TD_OSclip.

float out[4];
for( int s = sampleFrames; s > 0; --s )
{
    float input = *in;

    interp.process4(input, out);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Now a new error pops up: cannot call member function 'void interpolator_linear::process4x(float, float*)...without an object. I don't get it, isn't -> float out[4]; an object already?